# JSF html component on WebSphere 7.0

Tags: jsf, websphere

We are in the process of upgrading to WebSphere 7.0 on Windows 2008 R2.  Our applications currently run on WebSphere 6.1 on Windows 2003.

We use custom controls we wrote using JSF 1.1 in our applications.  Our controls seem to render and interact fine, however whenever we use a JSF HTML component such as:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>
...
<h:graphicImage url="#{MenuBean.bannerImagePath}" />
```

We get the following error:

```
com.ibm.ws.jsp.JspCoreException: Unable to convert string '#{MenuBean.bannerImagePath}' to class javax.el.ValueExpression for attribute url: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property Editor not registered with the PropertyEditorManager 
com.ibm.ws.jsp.JspCoreException: Unable to convert string '#{MenuBean.bannerImagePath}' to class javax.el.ValueExpression for attribute url: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property Editor not registered with the PropertyEditorManager
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.getValueFromPropertyEditorManager(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:939)
    at com.ibm._jsp._dashboard._jspx_meth_h_graphicImage_0(_dashboard.java:136)
    at com.ibm._jsp._dashboard._jspx_meth_f_view_0(_dashboard.java:436)
    at com.ibm._jsp._dashboard._jspService(_dashboard.java:109)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1583)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1523)
```

I have found an article on IBM's website giving a possible fix:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21318801

However I have removed the specified jars and am still receiving the error message.  Again our custom controls seem to work fine under WebSphere 7's JSF 1.2.

Thanks for any help you can provide.
Mike

Listing of WEB-INF\lib

- activation.jar
- commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
- commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
- commons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar
- commons-digester-1.8.1.jar
- commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar
- commons-io-1.4.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
- commons-pool-1.4.jar
- concurrent.jar
- dib-2.0.3.jar
- ibatis-2.3.4.726.jar
- ifc-3.1.0.jar
- imgipt-3.0.0.7.jar
- ironeyesql.jar
- iText-2.1.5.jar
- jasperreports-3.5.0.jar
- jaxen-full.jar
- jcommon-1.0.12.jar
- jdom.jar
- jdt-compiler-3.1.1.jar
- jfreechart-1.0.9.jar
- localization-3.1.0.jar
- log4j-1.2.15.jar
- mail.jar
- mflutil-3.1.0.jar
- mmwfoundation-3.1.0.jar
- RapidSpellWeb.jar
- saxpath.jar
- Stedmans.dict
- tcr-3.1.0.jar
- xalan.jar
- xercesImpl-2.4.0.jar
- xml-apis.jar

Comment: There must be still a JSF 1.1 API/impl wandering anywhere in the classpath. To start, can you list the libs in your `/WEB-INF/lib` here?

Comment: Your listing looks okay. No JSF nor `javaee` jars. How about `/jre/lib` and `/jre/lib/ext` and other external paths covered by the classpath? If it is also not there, then remains WebSphere itself. But it should in fact already ship with JSF 1.2 out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After recompiling against JSF 1.2, rebuilding config files, and updating tld files in the WEB-INF folder, I'm happy to report our problem is fixed.  Not exactly sure which fixed the problem.  Thanks for your time.

Mike

Comment: There should in fact be **no** JSF-specific TLD files in `/WEB-INF`. That can also be one of the causes of this problem. One should *never* extract the taglib JAR file to put the loose TLD files in the classpath, let alone to define it in the `web.xml`.